# Как сделать резиновый div[проблема в наследовании]

Tags: html, css

Имеется в наличии главный div ему задана ширина допустим в 210px,
а в этом диве имеются другие дивы (все они дочерни главному) их режим отображения block, они должны быть резиновыми, а родительский нет.
У меня получается, что дочерние дивы наследуют размер родителя
переназначать ширину не могу ибо нужна резина, помогите

Пример

```
#content
{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #d3d2ce;
    width: 100%;  
}
.topBlock
{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #6ca528;
}
<div id="content">
    <div class="topBlock">Просто текст проверка длины №1</div>
    <div class="topBlock">Просто текст где текста больше, проверка длины №1</div>
    <div class="topBlock">Текст проверка длины №3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может не width, а max-width?

Comment: у родителя должна быть определенная ширина, вопрос в потомках, я им писал min-width, но это не работает 0 реакции, а смысл в max-width?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я нашел такое решение

```
#content
{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #d3d2ca;
    width: 100%;
}
.topBlock
{  
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #6ca528;
    clear:both;
}
#content:after
{  
    content:"";
    display: block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#content
{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #d3d2ca;
    width: 100%;  
}
.topBlock
{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #6ca528;
    display: block;

}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div>
      <div class="topBlock">Просто текст проверка длины №1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="topBlock">Просто текст где текста больше, проверка длины №1</div>
    </div> 
    <div>
      <div class="topBlock">Текст проверка длины №3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: обновил, там видно что блоки растягиваются под всю длину родителя а должны только под свой текст

Comment: совсем не то, нужно чтобы размер дочерних элементов растягивался динамически под их содежимое, а вы предлагаете это заранее определить

Comment: тут либо js задействовать, либо переопределять `.topBlock` в `inline-block` либо `inline`. так как блочный элемент по умолчанию наследует размеры родителя.... а сторочный контента..

Comment: inline не нужен нужно чтобы все шло в столбик

Comment: Оберни в div ы, либо применяй позицирование, иначе без скриптов ничего не получиться....

Comment: глянь мой код, получилось)

Comment: Как вариант,но вставлять пустую строку как ограничитель блока....., я бы не стал.... своего рода костыль...

Comment: для вас костыль может быть и приемлемое решение, а мое решение двольно элегантное хотя бы потому что разметка не загрязняется дивами